# Mac OS X report via e-mail when a connection is done to specific ports (open in Firewall)

Tags: macos, port, smtp

I have ports open on a Mac for specific services. Is there a way to have the OS report through e-mail (Smtp) once a connection is established to one of the ports of interest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution - to use crontab. Create a file similar to the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
t=1197
while [ $t -gt 0 ]; do
ports="$(netstat -n | grep "ESTABLISHED" | awk '{print $4}' | grep -E '.*\.(80|5500|and other interested ports)$')"
if [ "$ports" ];
then t=0; echo $ports | mail -s "subject" your_mail@mail.com
fi
sleep 3
t=$((t-3))
done
```

Save it as `123.sh` and make it executable: `chmod +x /path/to/123.sh`. Create in your user directory `.crontab` file:

```
*/20 * * * * /path/to/123.sh
```

Checking will be executed every 3 seconds, but the difference in time between the notifications will not be less than 20 minutes, so as not to make it into a spam. You can change these numbers to other, what right for you. And finally - you need to specify the crontab daemon to file: `crontab ~/.crontab`

Comment: Thanks, perhaps I will try to accomplish this with CronniX